# need the search box to not refresh the page so the function will load the marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

// html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<head>


<title>
</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">


<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

// load google map

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? key=&sensor=true">

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.319914, 44.304771);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position:myLatlng, title:"Hello World!"});

var map = null;

function initialize() 
{

    var mapOptions = 
        {

            center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.319914, 44.304771),

        zoom: 12,

        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

        disableDefaultUI: true,


    };


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);


    //  marker.setMap(map);



}
```

// second map with marker

```
function initialize2() 
    {

            var mapOptions = 
        {

                center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.319914, 44.304771),

            zoom: 12,

            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

            disableDefaultUI: true,

        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

        marker.setMap(map);

    }   

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);



</script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<head>



<body>

<div id="map-canvas"/>

</div>
```

// button works to load second map

```
<button onclick="initialize2()">Enter ID</button>
```

// form will load second map but refreshs page and goes back to first map without marker

```
<form name="searchbox">
<input type="text" class="searchbox" name="searchterm"/>
<input type="image" src="images/opacbox1.png" class="searchbox_submit" value="Search"" ONCLICK="Javascript:doSearch()" onsubmit="javascript:doSearch()" />

<script type="text/javascript">


    function doSearch() 
    {

                searchvalue = document.searchbox.searchterm.value 

        if (searchvalue == "1") 
        {
                    initialize2();
                }
        else 
        {
            alert("no good");
        }   
        }


</script>

</body>



</html>
```

// if there is a better way to load markers with the seachbox or button im all ears been trying all day

// css

```
body

{
      }

#map-canvas 
{ 
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}

#searchwrapper 
{
    width:310px;
    height:40px;
    background-image:url('images/searchbox6.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    position:relative;
}

#searchwrapper form 
{ 
    display: inline; 
}

.searchbox 
{
    border:0px;
    background-color:transparent;
    position:absolute;
    top:4px;
    left:9px;
    width:256px;
    height:28px;
    color: #fff;
}

.searchbox_submit 
{
    border:0px; /*important*/
    background-color:transparent; /*important*/
    position:absolute; /*important*/
    top:4px;
    left:265px;
    width:32px;
    height:28px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

stop the form from summiting, like this:

```
 $('#upload').submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault(); 
     ... 
 });
```

Hope this helps :/

Comment: im not familiar with that code how and where would i implement it?

Comment: thank you so much figured it out it worked great spent 8 hours and a ton of time with someone on another thread trying to do something else thank you so much

Comment: actually that was a false started getting strange action upon further investigation an unclosed tag caused the problem and was just not refreshing but not returning the right values too read more into it and found that by adding onsubmit="return false" to my form tag it stopped the page refresh and fixed everything.